# Phrase "to make your bed" in Chinese?

Tags: phrase, equivalent-phrase

How do you say to "make your bed"? I've tried with Google translate but I don't believe it (zuo4 seems very wrong). Also searched this place but seems nobody asked this question yet.

is zhengli (整理) in any way appropirate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: iciba：make beds／the bed：铺床叠被，整理床铺 
also fig。make one's bed and lie in it：敢做敢当，
at jukuu １００ example sentences for ＂make bed＂

Comment: Orally speaking you can simply say 叠被子

Comment: A difference in reality will make a difference in idioms. Often, in China and in Europe, making a bed is a matter of folding the quilt. More and more US hotels are doing the same. A bed in those places has just a lower sheet and a quilt. It does not have an upper sheet and maybe a thin blanket plus a heavy blanket, with the top of edge of the upper sheet folded over the top edge of the blankets, as a bed might have in the US -- let alone a bedspread over the whole to be removed when you get into bed. So "making a bed" is less of a process than it was, say when my mother asked me to make mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

整理床 or 理床 is both appropriate to use in your case, but be careful when using the second one, although they present the same meaning, 理床 is more likely to get people confused with other words since it's too short to pronounce.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 整理 is appropriate, usually we say 整理床铺.

Answer (score 2):

We can use 拾牀. This means "Pick up your bed" as in pick up after yourself. This is good for cantonese and mandarin.

整理 is also ok. That means to sort clean up/take care of. So if you use this, you'll need to append the word bed to it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the verb 鋪牀

See also [zdic.net](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E9%93%BA%E5%BA%8A)

Answer (score 0):

“铺床”is  used  the  most.

sorry  but  I have never heard “理床”

"整理床铺” is ok and is more formal